# Woocommerce plugin extending coupons

Tags: woocommerce

I am in the process of writing a plugin for woocommerce. For the plugin I'd like to have a field where people can fill in a special code. Basically a coupon. This code will need to be checked against my own api to make sure it's a valid code.

I've tried to find some docs and information on how to add your own coupons. I've browsed through

https://docs.woocommerce.com

Looking for some api to add a hook to a custom function when it checks the coupon but could not find any.

Maybe I am approaching this wrong.

Does anyone know of some docs or an extension that has already done this to get me started?